# Aligning Text in React Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a very simple problem. I wanted to align the '01/01/2020' to the 'A00002'.

Pls see my codesandbox here
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/typography-5sl0w)

```
<div className={classes.root}>
  <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.marginTop2}>
    <span className={classes.fontBold}>Date:</span>{" "}
    <span className={classes.marginLeft3}>01/01/2020</span>
  </Typography>
  <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.marginTop1}>
    <span className={classes.fontBold}>Transaction Code:</span>{" "}
    <span className={classes.marginLeft3}>A00002</span>
  </Typography>
</div>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Date:                01/01/2020
Transaction Code:    A00002
```

Comment: I just tried this by setting position absolute and specifying top and left. Modifying marginTop1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Here's how i did it. I modified marginLeft3 class. Also look at my sandbox code

```
  marginLeft3: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 200,
    marginLeft: 3
  },
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typography-forked-eq4f1)

Comment: I've edited my question. The output should be like that

Answer (score 0):

Create a this class, instead of **marginLeft3** use **marginLeft120** for the date.

```
 marginLeft120: {
   marginLeft: 120
 },
```